# jquery loop animation with slidetoggle

Tags: jquery, loops, slidetoggle

is it possible to do this with a loop so i dont have to write click function for every div?

```
$("#q1").click(function(){
        $("#ans1").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    $("#q2").click(function(){
        $("#ans2").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    $("#q3").click(function(){
        $("#ans3").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    $("#q4").click(function(){
        $("#ans4").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    $("#q5").click(function(){
        $("#ans5").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    $("#q6").click(function(){
        $("#ans6").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    $("#q7").click(function(){
        $("#ans7").slideToggle("fast");
    });

    $("#q8").click(function(){
        $("#ans8").slideToggle("fast");
    });
```

where every id has a num that is same as the id num inside click function
like #q8 has ans#8
and if i add another id #q9, #ans9 i dont have to write click function?

every div also has a class... please tell me how can i do it when i click on question its ans should show

```
<div id="q1" class="question"><span id="q">Q:&nbsp;</span><span id="ul">How Do I Choose a Web Designer?</span></div>
            <div class="answer" id="ans1">some text</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you give classes for the two types?

Comment: You did it wrong from the beginning. As Sam says. Use classes and show your HTML structure so we can help

Comment: please help me every div has class .question and .answer and what i want is when click on .question its answer should show... like this <div id="q1" class="question"><span id="q">Q:&nbsp;</span><span id="ul">How Do I Choose a Web Designer?</span></div>
                <div class="answer" id="ans1"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this like below using one function. Add a attribut to the question div  `data-answerid`. It contains which answer to be shown. You don't have to repeat all to implement this functionality.

## HTML

```
<div class="question" data-answerid="ans1">
    <span id="q">Q:&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="ul">How Do I Choose a Web Designer?</span>
 </div>
 <div class="answer" id="ans1">some text</div>

<div class="question" data-answerid="ans2">
    <span id="q">Q:&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="ul">How Do I Choose a Web Designer?</span>
 </div>
 <div class="answer" id="ans2">some text</div>
```

## JS

```
$(".question").click(function(){
    var answer = $(this).data('answerid');
    $("#"+answer).slideToggle("fast");
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b69HH/)

Comment: Make sure not to use the same IDs multiple times. Any ID should appear only once in the DOM :)

Answer (score 3):

What Can be done is ..
put both your question and answer in a block ..
Say ...

```
<div class="qa-block">
    <div class="question">Q: How Do I Choose a Web Designer?</div>
    <div class="answer">some text</div>
</div>
```

Then change your script to ..

```
$('.question').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.answer').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

This will generalize your solution and avoids the use of IDs

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually use a class for all the question divs, write smthing like:

```
$('.questionclass').click(function {
   var qnr = this.attr('id');  //gets div ids...
   var anr = qnr.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); //strips id of non-numeric characters
   $("#ans"+anr).slideToggle("fast"); //toggles the answer div
});
```

I'm kind of sleepy so there may be some mistakes, but it should point you in the right direction.